# How to save the contents of the file to the pointer array in c language?

Tags: c, file

I want to write a function to read files. I want to save the contents of the file in a pointer array `data[len]`. `data[i]` saves the content of the i-th line of the file. I wrote the following function. But I don't know why the execution of the following function is abnormal. Sometimes nothing is output, and sometimes the last line of the file is output `len` times.

`addr` file content

```
1230400
24465566
56777899
0x82938484
```

c language

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fileRead(char *path,char *data[]){
    int len=0;
    char buffer[1030];
    FILE *fp;
    if(access(path,F_OK)){
        printf("file not exists.\n");   
        return -1;
    }else if(access(path,F_OK)){
        printf("No read permission.\n");    
        return -1;
    }
    fp = fopen(path,"r");
    while(fgets(buffer,1024,fp)!=NULL){
        // strcpy(data[len],buffer);
        data[len]=buffer;
        // data[len]+= '\0';
        len++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return len;
}


int main(){
    int a = 5;

    char *path="addr";
    char *data[1024]={};
    int len = fileRead(path,data);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%s",data[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

output

```
(base) cuiyujie@iZ2zegnwkvc9lo260pqfasZ:~/workspace/library/cUtils$ ./testFunc 
0x829384840x829384840x829384840x82938484

(base) cuiyujie@iZ2zegnwkvc9lo260pqfasZ:~/workspace/library/cUtils$ ./testFunc 
    0x8293840`0x8293840`0x8293840`0x8293840`
```

Thanks

Comment: `data[len]=buffer;` That won't work. There is only one `buffer` and all the `data` entries point to the same one. Even worse, `buffer` is a local variable which is invalid as soon as the function exits. Referencing such a variable outside the function is Undefined Behaviour. One solution is to make a copy: `data[len]=strdup(buffer)`. Don't forget to `free` the memory allocated by `strdup`.

Comment: Don't bother with the `access` checks.  Just check if `fopen` succeeds.  `fp = fopen(path,"r"); if( fp == NULL ){ perror(path); ... `

Comment: @kaylum That seems a complete and explained answer.

Comment: Thanks   But how to release the memory allocated by strdup? The buffer is an array above. Does this need to be released?